# Calling PHP function from within a string

Tags: php

I can't find a solution how to combine single and double quotes to echo HTML and call a function at the same time:

```
foreach ($result as $r) { 
    echo "<a href='get_permalink(get_page($r->id))'>".get_permalink(get_page($r->id)).'</a><br>';
}
```

Problem is this part is parsed as text, not php

```
"<a href='get_permalink(get_page($r->id))'>"
```

Cansome one help me to combine this? get_permalinks and get page are wordpress built in functions, so they should have function behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concat the string like this:

```
echo "<a href='". get_permalink(get_page($r->id)) . "'>" . get_permalink(get_page($r->id)) . "</a><br>";
```

Also if you want to know what's the difference between single and double quotes see this:
[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/3933332)

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a function inside double `"` quotes.

```
foreach ($result as $r)
        { 
            echo "<a href='".get_permalink(get_page($r->id))."'>".get_permalink(get_page($r->id)).'</a><br>';
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to run PHP code when it's inside a string (unless with eval). However, you can use [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf) to separate code from string:

```
$url = get_permalink(get_page($r->id));
printf('<a href="%s">%1$s</a><br>', htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

The `%1$s` is a positional format specifier; this is done so that the encoded `$url` value only has to be passed once.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
if($result as $r)
{ 
  echo "<a href='" . get_permalink(get_page($r->id)) . "'>" . get_permalink(get_page($r->id)) . '</a><br>';
}
```